# Do I still need Xplorer with the New Experience UI for the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I once heard that the New Experience Update (NX) includes full file and media management onto the Xbox 360 Dashboard software. Is this true and why would I need the Xplorer software anymore? I have an unmodded (original) Xbox, is there a major limitation with the file management I can do on it?

Answer (score 1):

Xbox doesn't support copying data to and from xbox harddisk to a pc. You can use Homegroup or legacy sharing options in windows to play media content from your pc though.

If you need to copy something to xbox, via usb, you will need to use Xplorer software. But, that is not a good practice, as MS reserves the rights to ban your console, if they found traces of any pirated media content. If you have paid content, you can download the same over xbox directly, instead of copying using Xplorer.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that Microsoft scans for and is capable of detecting pirated media content? That strikes me as something that would be nearly impossible from a technical standpoint, and a waste of time besides (compared to going after cheaters).

Comment: @Brant, it's not really possible to produce evidence from Microsoft's side, given that they don't actually provide it when they do ban people, but [this reference](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2011/09/08/microsoft-issues-xbox-live-bans-to-alleged-dlc-thieves.aspx) to one ban and a host of "Microsoft bans 1 million+ consoles" articles strongly imply that they do use some authentication methods along those lines.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis: Ah, I was thinking of stuff like movies and music. I didn't think of DLC. Yeah, that'd be pretty easy to track...

Comment: @Brant, that is a good point ... "media content" is vague. Games are easy enough to track (depending on how they're licensed), but other content would be almost impossible, and the accuracy of the answer hinges almost entirely on what was meant.

Comment: Well, I was talking about DLC only. As for normal music and stuff, you can directly play them on 360. Why use xplorer then? Just plug in the device in usb port and play.